# Triggering Abode Edge Animation in external jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, triggers, adobe-edge

I am using Adobe Edge animate which works great however all my animations are triggering based on the timeline and instead I would like it to be triggered when the section is in view.

I can achieve this in several different ways including using waypoints or checking for an "active" class however all of these solutions require me to use external javascript / jQuery.  In order to move forward I just need a basic example of external JS triggering the edge animation, for example a simple click function.

I have tried several proposed solutions from other forums however none seem to work.

If you ave any suggestions please let me know!

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need to do

1. Create an external JavaScript file
2. Inside of edge go to the scripts tab and add it to your project
3. Create a symbol in edge and call it what ever you like (for example `nameOfSymbol`)
4. Add the following to your JavaScript file you made above

```
AdobeEdge.bootstrapCallback(function(compId) {
    var comp = AdobeEdge.getComposition(compId);
    AdobeEdge.Symbol.bindElementAction(compId, "stage", "nameOfSymbol", "click", function(sym, e) {
        myFunction();
    });
    function myFunction(){
        alert("It's working!!!");
    }  
}
```

I was having this problem for a long time but discovered this process.  You can also animate symbols on the stage using your external JavaScript file.  Just add this part to the `bootstrapCallback` function

```
comp.getStage().play('LABEL'); // this will play the stage frame label 
comp.getStage().getSymbol("nameOfASymbol").play('LABEL'); // this will play a symbol timeline nested inside the main stage
```